# How to tell why my activity is paused on startup?

Tags: android

I have kind of an odd question. I noticed that on my main phone, a Samsung Galaxy S4 running 4.4.2, there is some software or setting installed which causes every app, when launched, to enter the pause state briefly when loading, so onResume gets called twice. But this does NOT happen on my wife's S4 running 4.3.  I'm trying to narrow down what could be causing this.

This happens with pretty much any app I have checked, including the Hello World app generated by IntelliJ 13, but not on the Android emulator and not on my wife's S4. What happens is:

```
(launch the app)
onResume()
onPause()
onResume()
(app is now active)
```

It's as if some piece of software is briefly taking foreground control for just a quick moment. I'd really like to find out what.

Anyone know what could be causing this, or how I might go about determining the reason why onPause is called on startup? If it's some other app intercepting I'd like to find out at least it's name. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an app that checks an app before a startup ex. Clean Master

Comment: The S4 has that weird overlay bar for app switching (the tab on the left side of the screen). Is that showing? If so, try holding the back button to turn it off, and then see if it goes away.

Comment: These are good suggestions. I disabled the "Multi View" thing you're talking about, and restarted the phone, and it still happens. I also uninstalled a number of different apps that I thought might possibly intercept app startup, and rebooted again, to no effect.  

I'm wondering if there's something I can do in my program to discover and log which app seized the foreground.

Comment: launch your activity after some time when system and other apps done there work. it is harder for other applications to intercept your application working. but if you launch your activity ,after some delay other application launch there activity then onpause method of your application call.i think that is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the culprit was [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop). Uninstalling this app made this behavior stop. I don't know why it does this, but I don't use the app much and it seems slightly suspicious so I just removed the app.

In case this helps anyone else: logging the visible activities in onResume/onPause did help me narrow this down a bit.

```
private void logVisibleProcesses() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService("activity");
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processList = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (processList != null) {
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcessInfo : processList) {
            if (appProcessInfo.importance == appProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_VISIBLE) {
                Log.e(TAG, "visible process: " + appProcessInfo.processName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```